# IDispatch::Invoke Returning E_INVALIDARG

Tags: c++, com, interop

I have an ATL COM component which raises a few events which are handled by managed (C# and VB.NET) code.  The component is currently used by a VS2005 VB.NET project (as an ActiveX control) and all of the events are raised and everything works.

However, in porting some of the code to C#, I noticed that all but one of the events are never raised. The only event which is raised passes no arguments back to the handler.  All others do.

```
// this function is auto-generated
HRESULT Fire_SomeEvent(VARIANT_BOOL inOriginated, IUserType * inUserType)
{
    CComVariant varResult;
    T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
    int nConnectionIndex;
    CComVariant* pvars = new CComVariant[2];
    int nConnections = m_vec.GetSize();

    for (nConnectionIndex = 0; nConnectionIndex < nConnections; nConnectionIndex++)
    {
        pT->Lock();
        CComPtr<IUnknown> sp = m_vec.GetAt(nConnectionIndex);
        pT->Unlock();
        IDispatch* pDispatch = reinterpret_cast<IDispatch*>(sp.p);
        if (pDispatch != NULL)
        {
            VariantClear(&varResult);
            pvars[1] = inOriginated;
            pvars[0] = inUserType;

            DISPPARAMS disp = { pvars, NULL, 2, 0 };
            pDispatch->Invoke(0x7, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &disp, &varResult, NULL, NULL);
        }
    }

    delete[] pvars;
    return varResult.scode;
}
```

`Invoke` is returning `0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)`.  Yet, in VB land, when used via the ActiveX wrapper, it works. Now, I'm no COM wizard by any means, and I just don't get it. I haven't been able to find anything applicable anywhere.

I thought that perhaps it had something to do with passing a UDT, but no; an almost identical version, with the `IUserType` replaced by a `LONG` also returns `E_INVALIDARG`.  Again, the single event which passes no arguments works.

A short example of how it may be used by the managed code. Nothing crazy here.

```
class Program
{
    private ComType _c;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _c = new ComType();
        _c.SomeEvent += _c_SomeEvent;    
        _c.DoSomethingWhichRaisesSomeEvent();    
    }

    static void _c_SomeEvent(bool b, IUserType udt)
    {
        // never called
    }
}
```

I would normally spend more time debugging before reaching out here, but I have to make a call here soon.  I either have to fix this, or abandon this interface and use another (which is sub-optimal for my purpose). So, hoping some of you COM pros have run into this before.

Comment: Reintepret_cast instead of QI for IDispatch is wrong.

Comment: I'd also double-check the vt values of the dispparams.  Is the 1st argument supposed to be IDispatch?  I'd expect the indexes to go in increasing order, not decreasing.

Comment: "UDT" is a red flag, it needs to be defined in the type library in order to survive a conversion from VT_RECORD.

Comment: @EricBrown: I can throw a `QueryInterface` in there, can't hurt to try, but I don't think that is the problem at hand (this code is automatically generated as well).  I'll check vt, but the indices do in fact go in decreasing order. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221479(v=vs.85).aspx and the section for `puArgErr [out]`.

Comment: @HansPassant: I thought the same, yet the same thing happens when passing, say, a `LONG`.  UDT's lead me down a path that didn't pan out, but of course I could have missed something.  The UDT in question is defined in the type library. Thanks for stopping by though, I know that you know your COM, and I'm at my wit's end here.

Comment: Looking at a couple of the other implementations floating around, I see that &varResult is always null.

Comment: And yes, the args do go backwards.  But I'd still doublecheck the vt values.

Comment: @EricBrown: I will, thanks Eric.  Can you point me to your reference(s) re: `varResult`?  I suppose I don't understand how that could be...

Comment: @EricBrown: So, I checked the vt values.  for `VARIANT_BOOL` it is `2` (`VT_I2`, two byte signed int) and for the `IUSerType` argument it is `9` (`VT_DISPATCH`, `IDispatch FAR*`).  Seems reasonable to me (`IUserType` implements `IDispatch`), but again, I don't really know COM.  I'm looking into it some more.

Comment: @EricBrown: Well holy crap; I changed the vt for the VARIANT_BOOL argument to 11 (VT_BOOL, duh) and it worked!  Yeesh.  Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.  Post an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check your vt values in your dispparam variants; many IDispatch implementations are quite particular about having everything line up.